# In React：Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

[image]
[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Root from './Root';
import './App.css'
import {session} from './libs/session';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends React.Component {

    public componentWillMount() {
        console.log("componentWillMount App");
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount App");
        console.log(window.location.search.replace(/\?/g,''));
        const urlParmes = window.location.search.replace(/\?/g,'');
        session.token = urlParmes.replace(/^token=/g,'');
    }


  public render() {
      if (session.token === '' || session.token === null || session.token === 'undefined') {
          console.log('no Jurisdiction');
          return (<Redirect to='/'/>);
      } else {
          console.log('has Jurisdiction')
      }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Root />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My purpose is to detect 'token' and then redirect it to the login page.
this  is why? please help me.  Thanks

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom Have you installed it correctly and it is listed in your package.json?

Comment: Can you put your code directly into your question please?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.7.3",
    "less": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.16.0"},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
    "ts-import-plugin": "^1.5.4",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"}

Comment: Just run "npm i react-router-dom" then restart the server, its worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

The Router must be installed, I solved with the installation using the following command:

```
npm i react-router-dom --save
```

Comment: Just to add, the `--save` flag will modify your `package.json`/`package-lock.json` file as well since it will save the info of any new package being installed by `npm` (or update the version of a package if an older version exists in there) to the JSON file.

Answer (score 11):

If you have installed the `react-router-dom` package then you need Typescript definitions for react-router-dom. Install `@types/react-router-dom` package. So either:

```
npm install @types/react-router-dom --save
```

or:

```
yarn add @types/react-router-dom
```

Answer (score -1):

From the react router docs it seems Redirect is part of react-router `import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'`

Comment: I'm use react-router-dom in here

Comment: All the problems have been solved，Thanks your  help ;because I install this package  in  @types,  this  node_modules   not  react-router-dom

Answer (score -3):

cd in app working directory and then run: `npm install @reach/router`

Comment: That package doesn't exist.